# C++ Ошибка exception from hresult 0x80041fe2 visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

При создании любого проекта, консольного, классического, вылезает такая ошибка, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? C# работает прекрасно, а вот c++ вообще никак.
Мои характеристики: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2017 Community

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Машина не виртуальная?

Comment: Советуют установить (если нет) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64

Comment: а где установить и как, я искал в инете, но ничего нет!?

Comment: машина не виртуальная

Comment: нет, не виртуальная, я бы указал если бы была таковой